# Bug css file stuck in server?

Tags: html, css, eclipse, tomcat8

I can't change one file in my project. Even deleted this file, its still exist in content send to client.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: Are you looking at the same location? The list of files in the directories are different.

Comment: Found answer here (its cache issue :) ): http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/30049/css-file-stuck-even-after-redownload-delete-and-reupload